# Show All Users as admin in laravel5.4

Tags: php, laravel, admin

I login as Admin in laravel and want see all users that are in users table,I used Rapid Authentication to login admin,my admin\login controller has this code:

```
 use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = 'admin/home';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('admin.login');
}
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

I Want in admin\home page I give list of projects and users are in users table,I used this code but say to me that users and projects undefind:

```
<div class="text-muted text-size-small">{{$users()->count()}}</div>

<div class="text-muted text-size-small">{{$projects()->count()}}</div>
```

How I can send Users and projects object to this view,that when admin login see their count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get an undefined error is because you did not send user  and project data to view.

Let's say you have an AdminHomeController with a method that returns a view

```
//Your route should look like this

    Route::get('admin/home','AdminHomeController@showUsers');

class AdminHomeController extends Controller {

    //AdminHomeController
        public function showUsers(){

        $users =User::all(); //get all users
    $projects =Project::all(); //get all projects


        return view('admin.home',['users'=>$users,'projects'=>$projects]); //send users and projects to view
        }
}
```

Do have a look at [laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: Thanks!But your solution don't Worked for me

Comment: Can you post the method in your  controller where route admin/home is pointing to here?

Comment: No Don't send method to controller and I give past error

Comment: I didnt get that. Have you been able to fix it ?